# How to resolve Kafka warning in ts-dev environment?

Tags: apache-kafka

Cleanup warnings ts-dev namespace in nonprod around Kafka.

whenever the logs will get generate for ts-dev around kafka there would be 1 warning message available.

```
message: "[Consumer clientId=consumer-tsdev.orders-service-message-8, groupId=tsdev.orders-service-message] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 960660 : {tsdev.verifications=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}"
```

We should have no warnings or errors when it comes to kakfa.

Comment: As the error says, `tsdev.verifications` doesn't exist as a topic. Please show us that it does